# Which application keeps trying to access default keyring?

Tags: 20.04, keyrings, gnome-keyring

I often get asked to enter the password to unlock the keyring, but there are no details on which application wants to unlock the keyring. Just that '**an** application' wants to unlock it.

Is there a way to see any more details on the application requesting the unlock?

Comment: If it asking before you open any apps, it is probably network related(wifi password?).  If it an app, can open and close one by one the ones you use.

Comment: @crip659 No it happens completely randomly when I haven't opened any new apps and my wifi hasn't reconnected

Comment: Is wifi trying to connect(or a VPN)?  Do you have auto logon on or you need password to log on?  Not quite clear.  Might be a setting in keyring that is not letting user in.  Think some time ago I had problem with VPN and google said a setting should set to all users.  Not quite sure if remembering correctly.

Comment: Keyring should have all the apps/services that are allowed/have passwords listed in it.  One of them is causing the problem, somehow.

Comment: Do you have any Online Accounts enabled in Settings | Online Accounts ?

Comment: @crip659 Wifi is already connected with its password saved. Auto log on is on. Is there no way to figure out the name / details of the application requesting this?

Comment: @PJSingh I do yes.

Comment: Keyring is not opened with auto logon enable, so any app listed in keyring will need to ask for your password.  Think the only way to fix, is to disable auto logon.  Choice is to type password once to log on, or type password every time an app needs to access keyring.  There might be other ways, but think they are less safe.

Comment: The Online Accounts require authorization from the key ring to use your stored passwords. These accounts usually take a few minutes to connect after you've logged in, and may try to reconnect if not authenticated. Therefore, this connection/re-connection process seems random to you. @crip659 already pointed out that the key ring is not unlocked during auto-login. Therefore, each time an online account tries to authenticate, key-ring asks you for authorization.

Comment: It is one thing I am not happy with Ubuntu, keyring asks for password, but does not say what app is asking for it.  Can use the cancel button and see if an app does not work.  My experience with chrome, says it does not matter much to the app.

Comment: @crip659 I'm fine with typing the password, I just want to know details on which app is requesting the password.

Comment: Keyring does not give this information.  Think I asked about this years ago, on one of the forums, since I thought it was bad security.  Don't think I got decent answer then either.  It should only be apps listed in keyring.  I would hit cancel instead of password and see if any act up.

Answer (score 0):

Is your system set to auto login when you start up?

If it's the case, the problem may be fixed by disabling auto login.
This can be done by going to settings - Users and disable automatic login

[image]

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: It keeps randomly asking me for the password even after I first enter it after booting up

Comment: I just got trolled by your username thinking it was some new feature. I now feel stupid.

Comment: lmaoooo 10 years later this username still delivers